# Show that $Z(t)=\exp{\sigma X(t)-(\sigma \mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2)t}$ is a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

I'm trying to show that $Z(t)=\exp{(\sigma X(t)-(\sigma \mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2)t)}$ is a martingale.

**Attempt:**

I want to show that $E[Z(t)|\mathcal{F}(s)] = Z(s)$

$E[Z(t)|\mathcal{F}(s)] = E[Z(t)/ Z(s) * Z(s)|\mathcal{F}(s)]$

$=Z(s)E[Z(t)/Z(s)|\mathcal{F}(s)] = Z(s)E[Z(t)/Z(s)]$

So at this point it looks like I need to determine that $E[Z(t)/Z(s)]=1$, but I'm not seeing it:

$E[Z(t)/Z(s)] = E[\exp{(\sigma (X(t)-X(s))-(t-s)(\sigma \mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2))}]$

I'm aware that $X(t)-X(s) \sim N(0,t)$, but I'm still not able to see why the above expectation should be 1.

-----edit 1 (comment from Kurt G.)-------

$X(t)-X(s)~\sim N(0,t-s)$

Let $X(t)-X(s)=u$

$E[\exp{\sigma(X(t)-X(s))}] = E[\exp{(\sigma u)}]$

$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(t-s)}}e^{\frac{-u^2}{2(t-s)}}*e^{\sigma u}du =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(t-s)}}e^{\sigma u - \frac{u^2}{2(t-s)}}du $

$=e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t-s)} * \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u)du = e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t-s)}$

$E[Z(t)/Z(s)] = e^{-(t-s)(\sigma \mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)} * e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t-s)}$

$=e^{-(t-s)\sigma \mu}$

$Z(s) E[Z(t)/Z(s)|\mathcal{F}(s)] = \exp{(\sigma X(s) - (\sigma \mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)s -(t-s)\sigma \mu})$

$=e^{\sigma X(s) - \sigma \mu t + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 s} \neq Z(s)$

Not sure where I've gone wrong.

Comment: I do not see it either because it is not true. Hint: set $\mu$ to zero and then use $X(t)-X(s)\sim N(0,t)$ by writing out that expectation using the normal PDF.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks for your response.  However, I'm still not quite able to show that Z(t) is a martingale.  Could you possibly take a look at my edit and let me know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Your calculations in the edit look correct but you forgot the first piece of my Hint: set $\mu$ to zero. :)

Comment: Ah, I see thanks!  So Z(t) is not a martingale in general-- only when mu=0.